# Subscribing to angular reactive form valueChanges

Tags: angular, forms, reactive

I'm subscribing to valueChanges on my Angular reactive form. However, I'm not seeing any value logged when I update the form. I'd like to see value changes in order to submit only those values that have changed. Why is nothing being logged?

The class:

```
form: FormGroup;
@Input() employee: Employee;

constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {
this.createForm();
}
ngOnInit() {
  this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
  console.log('value', value)
  })
}

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  if(this.employee &&
    changes.employee.currentValue !==
    changes.employee.previousValue) {
    this.updateForm();
  }
}

  createForm() {
  this.form = this._fb.group({
  name: [''],
  emergencyContactPhone: ['']
  }, {}
 )
}

updateForm() {
  this.form = this._fb.group({
    name: [this.employee.namePrefix],
    emergencyContactPhone: [this.employee.emergencyContact]
}, {}
)
}

submitForm() {
  if(this.form.valid) {
    this.saved.emit(this.form.value);
  }
}
```

The template:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (blur)="submitForm($event)">
<div class="ui-g ui-fluid">
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-6 ui-lg-6">
<div class="ui-grid-col-4">
<span>Name:</span>
</div>
<div class="ui-grid-col-8">
<input formControlName="name" name="name" type="text"pInputText/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-6 ui-lg-6">
<div class="ui-grid-col-4">
<span>Emergency Contact Phone:</span>
</div>
<div class="ui-grid-col-8">
<input formControlName="emergencyContactPhone" 
name="emergencyContactPhone" type="text" pInputText/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<button class="submit-button" (click)="submitForm()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong here. I create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-me3yfp) and it works.

Comment: @masterfloda, I see that when I remove my ngOnChanges logic which checks for 'this.employee', it works. So I believe this is because it takes a few milliseconds for my employee to come down. In your case, the employee is a hard coded value that comes in instantly. My valueChanges subscription was in ngOnInit, so it must have been subscribing before there was an employee to populate the form.  By putting my valueChanges subscription inside the employee check within ngOnChanges, the problem is resolved. Thank you very much for taking the time with this!